# MongoDB - Query for "is not null" not working

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm working with a MongoDB table and I have problems getting the documents with values different from null in some fields.
I assume that I'm using the `$ne` operator wrong, but, given this document:

```
{
  "createdAt" : "2022-04-07T13:18:18Z",
  "expired" : false,
  "responses": [
    {
      "id": "header",
      "options": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "text": ""
        }
      ],
      "textForSearch": null
    },
    {
      "id": "content",
      "options": [
        {
          "id": "content test 01",
          "text": "content test 01"
        },
        {
          "id": "content test 02",
          "text": "content test 02"
        }
      ],
      "title": "test title",
      "questionType": "selection",
      "textForSearch": null
    },
    {
      "id": "footer",
      "options": [
        {
          "id": "negative",
          "text": "Negative"
        },
        {
          "id": "positive",
          "text": "Positive"
        }
      ],
      "title": "test title",
      "questionType": "selection",
      "textForSearch": null
    },
    {
      "id": "test_id",
      "options": null,
      "title": "",
      "questionType": "text",
      "textForSearch": "comentario de test"
    }
  ]
}
```

The following query:

```
db.getCollection('table').find({"responses.textForSearch": {$ne: null} })
```

result in:

> Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$elemMatch` operator.

You may refer to [Single Query Condition](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition) to see the sample that using `dot notation` and `$elemMatch` produce the different results when using with `$not` or `$ne` operators.

```
db.collection.find({
  "responses": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "textForSearch": {
        $ne: null
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oHXphyd3h6C)

Comment: Im testing this and seems to work fine. I didnt know about $elemMatch, Im pretty new at mongodb.
Thank you very much for your time and contribution.